# foundation button full width

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am working on a app en need the buttons from foundation be the full width I think I tried searching but not get solution.

Here is code:

```
<a href="?p=telschema.html" class="button large" style='width=auto;'>Telschema</a><br>
```

And:

```
<a href="?p=telschema.html" class="button large" style='width=100%;'>Telschema</a><br>
```

It's not working.

Live example [here](http://tweestroomapp.mijnrovox.tk/?p=aspiranten.php):

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your syntax is incorrect. `style='width=`  should be `style='width:`

Try this.

```
<a href="?p=telschema.html" class="button large" style='width: 100%;'>Telschema</a>
```

Comment: Inline styling is never the answer. Use the 'expanded' class.

Answer (score 13):

Foundation has special class for this.

Use .expand class:

```
<a href="?p=telschema.html" class="button expand large">Telschema</a>
```